# Which windows subsystem is supported on a recovery disk

Tags: c++, windows, subsystem

When running a standard Windows 7 Installation Disk in recovery mode, if you open up the command line and run a custom-built application you will receive the error 'subsystem not supported'. I have tried linking with /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE, WINDOWS and NATIVE, none of these work.

I had a little difficulty with a partition table (and may have found a bug, or at least 'stupid' behaviour from the partition manager included in windows) and so wrote a utility to fix it. My program uses 'Windows.h' to import `CreateFile`, however if need be I can use only standard C++ (Or even standard C) with no windows specific headers.

What do I need to do to get an application running?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Is this reproducible with a simple "Hello World" program, or do you get the problem when you start using CreateFile?  What is the output of `objdump -p` on your program w.r.t. "Subsystem"?  http://old.nabble.com/Finding-an-executable's-Windows-subsystem-td22897545.html

Comment: Using visual studio 2010, C++ (Using static runtime), when I get a chance in an hour I will try using an empty project and then with just a printf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Recovery Environment is a superset of the Windows Preinstallation Environment.

Windows PE is a stripped down version of windows, lacking many subsystems including WoW (Windows on Windows).

This means that 32bit executables (or anything with a 32bit component) WILL NOT RUN on a 64-bit Windows PE disk. (Note that WinPE 32 cannot install/repair 64 bit systems and vice-versa).

The solution to my problem was to compile to 64 bit code -- a descriptive error message would have been nice Microsoft :|

Found after much searching:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the C++ CRT in any way? I don't think that's supported. I'd even doubt that `CreateFile` is appropriate; and look into `NtCreateFile` instead.

Comment: Well there _must_ be a runtime... There are a wide range of tools that run on the recovery console, does anyone know of a page where I can find the requirements? I couldn't turn up anything through google, but may have been typing the wrong thing.

Comment: You're thinking of the native runtime (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447.aspx). Fortunately recovery mode and Windows PE run in Win32, just with some components removed.